# Calculate sum of multiple items in array in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to get a sum for items I have within a class. To explain you better, I'm having cart object for which I can calculate the total sum with this method:

```
 public decimal ComputeTotalValue()
        {
            return itemCollection.Sum(e => e.Item.Price*e.Quantity);                        
        }
```

The item object in our case is this one:

```
public class CartItem
        {
            public RestItem Item { get; set; }
            public int Quantity { get; set; }
        }
```

Now the RestItem class has these properties:

```
public class RestItem
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int InStockNow { get; set; }
        public int Order { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public bool HasImage { get; set; }
        public bool HasModifiers { get; set; }
        public string PLU { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public byte[] ImageArray { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<ModifierOption> Modifiers { get; set; }
    }
```

The last property, Modifiers is new property which I included today and this is the content:

```
public class ModifierOption
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }            
    }
```

What I want to achieve is when the ComputeTotalValue is called, If there are ModifierOption fields as well, I want to calculate the sum of those fields as well and include the result in the total sum.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add price of modifiers to price of your item, can't you?

```
public decimal ComputeTotalValue()
{
   return itemCollection.Sum(e => (e.Item.Price + e.Item.Modifiers.Sum(m=>m.Price))*e.Quantity);                        
}
```

Comment: what if for some items I have null?

Comment: Check for null then! And handle them as you consider right. I provided only basic solution - you can extend it if there is a need

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
public class RestItem
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int InStockNow { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public bool HasImage { get; set; }
    public bool HasModifiers { get; set; }
    public string PLU { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageArray { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ModifierOption> Modifiers { get; set; }

    public decimal ComputeTotalPrice() {
        return (this.Modifiers?.Sum(x => x.Price) ?? 0) + Price;
    }
}

public decimal ComputeTotalPrice(){ 
    return itemCollection?.Sum(x => x.ComputeTotalPrice()) ?? 0;
}
```